# Clojure Record Registration

Tags: clojure, deserialization

Is there a best practice for this?

Basically, I'm `prn-str`-ing record instances to `string`s, to persist to a database. To deserialize, I need to provide the `clojure.edn/read-string` function a map of tag symbols to constructor functions.

This means that every defined record needs to register itself in a global place with its tag symbol and its constructor function. Fine. I'm using a `ref`, but could have gone with a `var` and `alter-var-root`. It doesn't really matter.

The bigger issue is that unless the namespace is specifically loaded, this registration doesn't happen.

I'm building an API that's extensible. Anyone who defines a record that satisfies a protocol can use it. Basically, they declare a dependency on my lib, define records that satisfy my protocol, and get serde for free.

I can't a priori know where API lib users put their defined records.

There must be a best practice for this. Maybe just a convention of `main` namespaces that the end user JAR requires. Maybe something fancier with Leiningen `project.clj` declaration that causes `-m` on JAR load?

Answer (score -1):

I would discourage this approach, as [it is almost an antipattern](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/12/22/the-anti-pattern-eavil-database-design/) in DB usage.

If you don't want to make a complicated schema, you could use Datomic Free which only requires declaring the types of each field.   You can see a working example here:   https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic     Simply clone the repo and execute `lein test`.

In particular, [the James Bond example](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo_datomic/bond.clj) shows how to declare attributes (the keys in a Clojure map):

```
 ; Create some new attributes. Required args are the attribute name (an optionally namespaced
  ; keyword) and the attribute type (full listing at http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html). We wrap
  ; the new attribute definitions in a transaction and immediately commit them into the DB.
  (td/transact *conn* ;   required              required              zero-or-more
                      ;  <attr name>         <attr value type>       <optional specs ...>
    (td/new-attribute   :person/name         :db.type/string         :db.unique/value)      ; each name      is unique
    (td/new-attribute   :person/secret-id    :db.type/long           :db.unique/value)      ; each secret-id is unique
    (td/new-attribute   :weapon/type         :db.type/ref            :db.cardinality/many)  ; one may have many weapons
    (td/new-attribute   :location            :db.type/string)     ; all default values
    (td/new-attribute   :favorite-weapon     :db.type/keyword ))  ; all default values

  ; Create some "enum" values. These are degenerate entities that serve the same purpose as an
  ; enumerated value in Java (these entities will never have any attributes). Again, we
  ; wrap our new enum values in a transaction and commit them into the DB.
  (td/transact *conn*
    (td/new-enum :weapon/gun)
    (td/new-enum :weapon/knife)
    (td/new-enum :weapon/guile)
    (td/new-enum :weapon/wit))
```

You can then transact Clojure maps (aka "records") into the DB like so:

```
; Create some antagonists and load them into the db.  We can specify some of the attribute-value
  ; pairs at the time of creation, and add others later. Note that whenever we are adding multiple
  ; values for an attribute in a single step (e.g. :weapon/type), we must wrap all of the values
  ; in a set. Note that the set implies there can never be duplicate weapons for any one person.
  ; As before, we immediately commit the new entities into the DB.
  (td/transact *conn*
    (td/new-entity { :person/name "James Bond" :location "London"     :weapon/type #{ :weapon/gun :weapon/wit   } } )
    (td/new-entity { :person/name "M"          :location "London"     :weapon/type #{ :weapon/gun :weapon/guile } } )
    (td/new-entity { :person/name "Dr No"      :location "Caribbean"  :weapon/type    :weapon/gun                 } ))
```

The rest of the example shows how to query the Datomic DB and perform other operations.

Comment: I use records to achieve single dispatch on first arg type for any protocols I define. Sure, I could use maps. But then I'd just dispatch on some `:type` field using multimethods anyway. And because the implementation method is in a namespace *_that isn't yet loaded_*, it will fail anyway. The same problem persists.